# Simplify X = A(AB)' + A'B'C + ABC

Tags: boolean-algebra

Why is this way of simplifying the Boolean expression wrong?

```
X = A(AB)' + A'B'C + ABC
  = A(AB)' + C(A'B'+AB) //A'+A = 1
  = A(AB)' + C
  = A(A'+B')+ C
  = (AA')+AB'+ C
  = AB'+ C
```

Is it wrong because `C(A'B'+AB) ≠ C(1)`? 
Can someone explain to me why they are not the same? Thank you.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A'B'\ne(AB)'$

By de Morgan: $$A'B'=(A+B)'$$

Comment: oh you are right! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, why should $A'B' + AB = 1$? The information $A' + A = 1$ only helps if you get to that in some way, but you can't pull out $B$ or $B'.$

If you want to see why they are not the same, just write down the truth tables and compare them.